# What is the appropriate word to use to describe when I mentally repeat various words that I learned in English to instill them in my head?

Tags: word-request

Sometimes when I'm sitting and doing nothing, I repeat, in my head, various words that I learned in English. I do that in order to instill those words in my head. Which of the following **words** would be correct(if any) to describe this action?

TFD definitions below

**Review**: To look over, study, or examine again: reviewed last week's lesson.

**Practice**: To do or perform (something) repeatedly in order to acquire or polish a skill: practice a dance step.

Or perhaps simply *repeat*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often we have situations where many words can be suitable to describe something, and we can choose among them for the different connotations they carry.

- Yes, **review** is a great choice for mentally going over something you've learned earlier. It means literally looking at something again—"re" plus "view."
- Yes, it's true that by repeating the words to yourself you are **practicing** them—performing them to get better.
- Another word that combines a bit of both ideas is **rehearse**. It combines the idea of *practice*—performing an action or sequence in order to learn it better—with the "re-" prefix, implying that you're doing so repetitively. Not all "review" activities could be called "rehearsing"—we talk of orchestras, ballet companies, and choirs "rehearsing," but it wouldn't be the best choice for students studying class notes—but it is appropriate for intellectual exercises with an emphasis on an action, e.g. "The lawyer *rehearsed* the points of her defense."

Answer (score 0):

Read the words and try to **internalize them**.
This can be done by reviewing them over several days.

Once you **internalize them** by creating sentences, you know them.

However, it's best to try and **create sentences with them**.
Because otherwise, you probably won't remember them.

> Read for Vocabulary Acquisition Reading extensively in your target
> language exposes you to a wide range of vocabulary. Whether it's
> books, news articles, or online content, reading helps you encounter
> new words in different contexts.
>
> Additionally, writing actively engages your brain in processing and
> **internalizing vocabulary**. Practice writing sentences or short
> paragraphs using new words, ensuring that you understand their
> meanings and can use them accurately.
> [vocabulary acquisition](https://lingopie.com/blog/effective-strategis-for-building-vocabulary-in-a-new-language/#:%7E:text=Reading%20extensively%20in%20your%20target,in%20processing%20and%20internalizing%20vocabulary.)